# Parse and return proper JSON with JQ after inverse GREP

Tags: json, shell, grep, jq, tmux

I've been struggling way too much with something that seems to simple to struggle with.

Routinely throughout the day I use iOs shortcuts to monitor one of my servers, and the shortcuts app is very finicky when it comes to dealing with JSON objects.

I need to return a perfectly formatted (without nesting) array; i.e :

```
{
  {
    "term": "alpha"
  },
  {
    "term": "beta"
  },
  {
    "term": "gamma"
  },
}
```

The data is being fetched from an internal API call, of which I need to filter out values from already existing terms.
I want to know which objects are returned from the API that are **NOT currently** a running tmux of same name.

Here's a non-formatted return from API call :

```
{
  "online_terms": [
    {
      "term": "alpha"
    },
    {
      "term": "beta"
    },
    {
      "term": "gamma"
    }
  ],
  "total": 3,
}
```

Here's the one-liner used currently :

```
list=$(tmux list-sessions -F \#S); curl https://myapi.call| jq -r '.online_terms[] | .term' | grep -v $list
```

The $list will contain multiple line LS style names of current running tmux sessions. i.e :

```
alpha
omega
kappa
```

That's what I've been using so far, but it's wacky at best. To clarify, declared all my tmux sessions into the **$list** variable, then do the API call, parse out the nested values i need, inverse grep against the **$list** ... not ideal !

And it only returns *single line names*, i.e (filtered out alpha):

```
beta
gamma
```

I've not been able to parse it into the type of object explained above despite many attempts to slurp back the raw data into JQ.

I'm welcome to any suggestions as to how to inverse grep the **tmux ls** values more cleanly, or parse into a proper JSON object, thank you in advance for any help !

Comment: Please review [mcve]. We don't need to see the full output from the call to curl, but a representative sample, or at least a sample from the output from `jq .all`, would be helpful.  Likewise an example of $list.

Comment: @peak Yes, my sincere apologies, realize the original post was incomplete, hope it's sufficient now, thanks

Comment: Yes, it's complete, but there seems to be some inconsistency between the illustration and the requirements.  Also, please fix the first array to make it valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show how jq can be used to solve the problem without any hackery, let's first suppose that the blacklist is somehow available as a text file, say blacklist.txt:

```
alpha
omega
kappa
```

Then you could use an invocation of jq along the following lines:

```
< blacklist.txt jq --argjson curl "$(curl https://myapi.call)" -Rn '
  [inputs] as $blacklist
  | [ $curl
      | .online_terms[]
      | select( .term | IN($blacklist[]) | not) ]'
```

Here, the output of the curl command has been provided to jq using the `--argjson` option.

This solution can readily be modified to handle other sources of the black list.

#### An alternative

You could also provide the output of the curl command to jq via STDIN, but then you'd first have to convert the textual blacklist into JSON. This could be done by invoking jq once more:

```
curl https://myapi.call | 
  jq --argjson blacklist "$(jq -Rn '[inputs]' blacklist.txt)" '
    [.online_terms[]
     | select( .term | IN($blacklist[]) | not)]'
```

Not pretty, but it serves to highlight the fact that things would be somewhat simpler if your black list generator could provide the black list as JSON.

Comment: Super super awesome! Thank you for giving a concrete example of JQ's power. We all know it's fully capable from the MAN pages, but requires a deep understanding of JSON and arrays for the more complex things. I used your  1st proposed version, with `echo "$(tmux ls)" | ` instead of text file, thanks ! worked first try

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is offered mainly because it is similar to the one proposed by the OP, though it uses `comm` rather than `grep`, and assumes the blacklist is in a text file, blacklist.txt:

```
curl https://myapi.call |
 jq -r '[.online_terms[].term] | sort[]' |
 comm -23 - <(sort blacklist.txt) |
 jq -Rn '[{term: inputs}]'
```

This has the disadvantage of requiring a second invocation of jq to reconstruct a JSON entity; it also requires two sorting operations, which might not be desirable, though of course the sorting of the blacklist could be skipped if it is already sorted.

Comment: thanks for sharing, is there any value in using `comm` instead of `grep` or `diff` when it requires both list to be preemptively sorted?

Comment: `comm` should be more efficient for the task, and might be easier to use correctly and or safely.